# Проблема с процентами

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
});

function calculate(event) {
  const clickedButtonValue = event.target.value;

  if (clickedButtonValue === '=') {  
    if (display.value !== '') {
      let str = display.value
        .replace(/\^/g, "**")
        .replace(/%(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, "*($1/100)");        
        
      display.value = eval( str );
    }    
  } else if (clickedButtonValue === 'C') {  
    display.value = '';
  } else {
    display.value += clickedButtonValue;
  }
  
  
}

// вот здесь была лишняя скобка
function soundClick2() {
  var audio = new Audio(); 
  audio.src = 'https://www.myinstants.com//media/sounds/0447-mp3cut.mp3'; 
  audio.autoplay = true; }
  const s = window.screen;
  
const w = (q.width = s.width);
const h = (q.height = s.height);
const ctx = q.getContext("2d");

const p = Array(Math.floor(w / 10) + 1).fill(0);

const random = (items) => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  p.map((v, i) => {
    ctx.fillText(random(hex), i * 10, v);
    p[i] = v >= h || v > 50 + 10000 * Math.random() ? 0 : v + 10;
  });
}, 1000 / 30);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222831;
  font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  
}

.calculator {
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
  position: absolute;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #f8d407;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: right;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 
  
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.operator {
  background-color: #888888;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.imgholder
{
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
/* thumbnails css | pcvector.net */
.imgholder img
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 5;
}
.imgholder figcaption
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 120%;
   width: 120px;
   color: #004E87;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff;
   z-index: 4;
}
/* decoration css | pcvector.net */
.imgholder .circle
{
   position: absolute;
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <canvas id=q></canvas>
    
</head>

<body>

  <div class="imgholder">
    <div class="outer1 circle"></div>
    <div class="outer2 circle"></div>
    <figure>
        <img src="../images/linnea-ahlman.jpg" />
        <figcaption class="caption">Linnea Ahlman</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imgholder">
    <div class="outer1 circle"></div>
    <div class="outer2 circle"></div>
    <figure>
        <img src="../images/daria-werbowy.jpg" />
        <figcaption class="caption">Daria Werbowy</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

  <div class="calculator">

    

    <input type="text" class="display" disabled>

    

    <div class="keys">

      

      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="7">7</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="8">8</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="9">9</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="+">+</button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="4">4</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="5">5</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="6">6</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="-">-</button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="1">1</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="2">2</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="3">3</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="*">*</button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="C">C</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="0">0</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="/">/</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick()"><button value="=" class="operator">=</button></p>    
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="(">(</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value=")">)</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="^">^</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="%">%</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Добрый день уже 2 дня не как не могу сделать, так чтобы проценты работали, а также нужно поставить кнопку backspace. И как реализовать, чтобы при вводе одного оператора нельзя было вводить другой и чтобы после вывода ответа, когда ты вводишь, новое число ответ просто стирался, а не продолжал писать в ответ

Answer (score 3):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка - лишняя `{` перед оглашением `function soundClick2()`

После того как я убрал скобку, проценты у меня заработали (Chrome 85)

Для того, чтобы добавить `backspace`, пройдитесь по строке и удалите последний символ:

`var ваша_строка = ваш_элемент.value;`

`var строкаМинусОдин = ваша_строка.substring(0, str.length - 1);`

Или

`var ваша_строка = ваш_элемент.value;`

`var строкаМинусОдин = ваша_строка.slice(0, -1);`

Для очищения строки вы можете добавить класс к кнопке `=`, когда она нажимается и выполнить проверку на класс у этой кнопки, если класс нажатой `=` есть, то при нажатии любой другой кнопки, нужно очистить строку и убрать класс нажатой `=`, а все остальные кнопки должны нормально работать, только если этого класса у `=` нету.

Или обратить эту логику и добавить всем кнопкам класс, а у нажатой `=` убирать класс, если проверка на класс у нажатой `=` показывает, что класса нету, то любая кнопка с этим классом при нажатии очищает строку элемента `.display`, если класс у `=` есть, то все кнопки работают нормально.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const eq = document.getElementById("eq");

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
});

function calculate(event) {
  const clickedButtonValue = event.target.value;

  if (clickedButtonValue === '=') {  
    if (display.value !== '') {
      let str = display.value
        .replace(/\^/g, "**")
        .replace(/%(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, "*($1/100)");        
        
      display.value = eval( str );
      eq.classList.add("pressed");
    }    
  } else if (clickedButtonValue === 'C') {  
    display.value = '';
  }
    else if (clickedButtonValue === 'back' && clickedButtonValue !== '') {
     display.value = display.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
  else {
    if(eq.classList.contains("pressed")){
      display.value = '';
      eq.classList.remove("pressed");
    }
    display.value += clickedButtonValue;
  }
  
  
}


function soundClick2() {
  var audio = new Audio(); 
  audio.src = 'https://www.myinstants.com//media/sounds/0447-mp3cut.mp3'; 
  audio.autoplay = true; }
  const s = window.screen;
  
const w = (q.width = s.width);
const h = (q.height = s.height);
const ctx = q.getContext("2d");

const p = Array(Math.floor(w / 10) + 1).fill(0);

const random = (items) => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  p.map((v, i) => {
    ctx.fillText(random(hex), i * 10, v);
    p[i] = v >= h || v > 50 + 10000 * Math.random() ? 0 : v + 10;
  });
}, 1000 / 30);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222831;
  font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  
}

.calculator {
  width: 350px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
  position: absolute;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #f8d407;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: right;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 
  
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled] {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: auto;
}

.operator {
  background-color: #888888;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.imgholder
{
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
/* thumbnails css | pcvector.net */
.imgholder img
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 5;
}
.imgholder figcaption
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 120%;
   width: 120px;
   color: #004E87;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff;
   z-index: 4;
}
/* decoration css | pcvector.net */
.imgholder .circle
{
   position: absolute;
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.keys .row:first-child p:last-child {
  transform: scale(-1, 1)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <canvas id=q></canvas>
    
</head>

<body>

  <div class="imgholder">
    <div class="outer1 circle"></div>
    <div class="outer2 circle"></div>
    <figure>
        <img src="../images/linnea-ahlman.jpg" />
        <figcaption class="caption">Linnea Ahlman</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imgholder">
    <div class="outer1 circle"></div>
    <div class="outer2 circle"></div>
    <figure>
        <img src="../images/daria-werbowy.jpg" />
        <figcaption class="caption">Daria Werbowy</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

  <div class="calculator">

    

    <input type="text" class="display" disabled>

    

    <div class="keys">

      

      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="7">7</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="8">8</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="9">9</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="+">+</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="back">&#x2794;</button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="4">4</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="5">5</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="6">6</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="-">-</button></p>
        <p><button disabled></button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="1">1</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="2">2</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="3">3</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="*">*</button></p>
        <p><button disabled></button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="C">C</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="0">0</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="/">/</button></p>
        <p id="eq" onclick="soundClick()"><button value="=" class="operator">=</button></p>
        <p><button disabled></button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="(">(</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value=")">)</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="^">^</button></p>
        <p onclick="soundClick2()"><button value="%">%</button></p>
        <p><button disabled></button></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: если вам  не трудно можете отредактировать мой код и показать я убрал как вы сказала лишнию скобку но все равно не заработало и очень прошу реализовать функцию backspace в моем коде

Comment: @VenDETTA я поправил ваш код, но правка проходит модерацию, место скобки указал комментарием в JS блоке, сегодня попробую реализовать backspace, как время будет, но без нормального CSS, только функционал.

Кстати, попробуйте выполнить код в моем ответе, там всё работало, пока правка обрабатывается модераторами.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ  но как странно он опять не работ при вводе 20+20% кнопка = не реагирует даже

Comment: @VenDETTA так не от чего считать 20%, ваш ввод должен быть `a%b`, где a - кол-во процентов, b -  число, от которого считаются проценты. 
В консоли видно, что у вас есть еще ошибка, вы запускаете функцию `soundClick()` при нажатии `=`, но вы ее не указали в JS

Comment: да это я знаю я сам убрал этот звук с JS потом добавлю но все равно проценты не правильно считает

Comment: @VenDETTA Я только что ввёл `20%200` в коде своего ответа и в коде вашего вопроса, даёт результат 40, то есть всё работает.

Comment: да я тоже попробовал работает я ток одно не понял а почему нельзя написать 50+20% чтобы так работало

Comment: @VenDETTA потому что форма записи требует числа после знака `%`, иначе код не увидит, от какого числа считать проценты, ваш код работает по формуле, как я написал выше

Comment: а понятно а это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @VenDETTA переписать логику высчитывания процентов из значения в желтой строке с помощью js, но вы сначала для себя должны понять, откуда код должен брать число, от которого считать процент. Вы привели математическое выражение `50+20%`, вы хотите, чтобы 20% считались от 50? Нужно понимать позицию числа 50 в строке, будет ли оно сначала, или после знака `%` как сейчас. Посмотрите реализации других калькуляторов в интернете. Тот же калькулятор в Google поисковике так же работает.
[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/scientific)
[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculator)

Comment: ну на данный момент мой калькулятор работает 20%5 так он выдает ответ а просто хотел бы сделать так что при наборе 20+50% так тоже выдавал ответ и еще самое главное это blackspace

Comment: @VenDETTA добавил `backspace`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: А можно реализовать так чтобы после вывода ответа,ответ стирался при вводе новых цифр

Comment: @VenDETTA да, я это пишу на классах, уже добавил для вас в ответе